How to rename the array of StructType fields in PySpark?
I need to read a JSON in French language and want to convert it English column names.
e.g.  The Schema is like this
 |-- unites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statutDiffusionUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- unitePurgeeUnite: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dateCreationUnite: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sigleUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sexeUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- periodesUnite: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dateFin: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dateDebut: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- etatAdministratifUnite: string (nullable = true)

I can use the withColumn and alias OR withColumnRenamed to rename the top level.  But I have problem to rename the array of struct (e.g. the periodesUnite.dateFin above).
My plan is to create a new English column mapping that periodesUnite: array first (e.g.
new column named 'UnitsPeriods') and then create another column mapping the unites: array (e.g. named 'Units')  After that, replace the new 'Units.periodesUnite' by the new column 'UnitsPeriods'.
The DF will be like this:
 |-- unites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statutDiffusionUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- unitePurgeeUnite: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dateCreationUnite: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sigleUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sexeUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- periodesUnite: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dateFin: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dateDebut: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- etatAdministratifUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Units: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- broadcast_status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- is_purged: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- creation_date: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- symbol: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sex: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- UnitPeriods: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dateFin: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dateDebut: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- etatAdministratifUnite: string (nullable = true)
 |-- UnitsPeriods: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- end_date: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- start_date: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- administrative_state: string (nullable = true)

I use the following codes to create the new column, but I can't find a way to fill the values from the 'unites.periodesUnite' to the new column 'UnitsPeriods'
newdf = df.withColumn('UnitsPeriods', F.array(F.struct(*[F.lit(None).cast(f.dataType).alias(fr_eng_name_mappings[f.name] if f.name in fr_eng_name_mappings else f.name) for f in unit_period_schema]))) \

I also notice that the original column has the nullable set to true, but the new one has it set to false.  Is there a way to set the nullable for the column?

I find a way to do it.  Just need to create a new Schema using English name and cast it.
E.g.
eng_unit_schema= StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("score", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("broadcast_status", StringType(), True),
    StructField("is_purged", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("creation_date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("symbol", StringType(), True),
    StructField("sex", StringType(), True)
    StructField("periods", ArrayType(unit_period_schema), True),
])

unit_period_schema= StructType([
    StructField("end_date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("start_date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("administrative_state", StringType(), True),
])

 df.select(F.col('unites').cast(ArrayType(eng_unit_schema)).alias('units'))

